# Referencing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions causes a higher version referenced exception on System.Runtime

Tags: exception, .net-core-3.1, .net-standard-2.1

I'm trying to reference AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions in a .Net Standard 2.1 library with version=3.1.0 being the latest as of writing, however, I'm getting a higher version than referenced exception thrown at compile-time.

I have tried explicitly stating the FrameworkRuntimeVersion in my project file, added a reference to the latest System.Runtime on nuget, even tried to force an update in the app.config. I can't believe it's this difficult to explicitly force the .Net Standard library to use a higher version.

The exception:

[image]

Comment: There's no `app.config` in .NET Core. Did you try adding the package to a .NET Framework project? Or tried to add a reference directly instead of using the package? .NET Framework isn't compatible with .NET Standard 2.1

Comment: In ASP.NET Core applications `AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` is added as part of the project template itself. If there were any incompatibilities, all ASP.NET Core 3.1 projects would fail

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i was just trying the app.config route, hoped I was missing something. As for the project, I'm adding the reference, like I said, to a .Net Standard 2.1 class library, not to an ASP.net Core applications

Comment: You have to explain what you did.  That's a package, not a reference. And .NET Core/Standard has *no* app.config. .NET Standard 2.1 class libraries can only be used by .NET Core applications which *don't* have an `app.config` either. They don't *run* either, they have to be called from an executable program.

Comment: What kind of application did you create, ie where did you try to call that .NET Standard library from? A Winforms app? WPF? ASP.NET? Console? Which runtime does it target?

Comment: I want to move my ASP.net Core's conventional startup files into a class library, as I want to maintain the startups without recompiling and deploying the main asp.net core application the whole time. I'll add a screenshot

Comment: No, don't add a screenshot. Explain what you did - you tried to create a web app targeting a specific .NET Core version. Which one? You created a class library. Then what? Did you add the Abstractions package there? Or did you add a hard-coded reference to the DLL? Did you mix up runtime versions perhaps?

Comment: I created a ASP.net Core web api, targeting .net 3.1. I then added a .Net Standard 2.1 class library to the project, and added the Abstractions reference to the .Net Standard 2.1. I added a StartupDevelopment class to the class library and in the Configure(...) method, when mapping the endpoints (endpoints.MapGet("/", async context => { ... });), it fails with that exception. If I change the UseEndpoints to UseMvcDefaultRoute(), it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple.

I changed the class library to rather target the full .Net Core 3.1 rather than relying on .Net Standard 2.1